# Delete parent without deleting children

Tags: foreign-key, delete

I have three table: Products, Stocked products, sold products.

Products and 'stocked products' are different tables because there are different batches of the same product stocked with different serial numbers. here are the important rows in those tables:

Products:

| Products |
| --- |
| ID |
| Designation |

Stocked Products:

| StockedProducts |
| --- |
| ID |
| Quantity |
| BatchSerialNumber |

Sold Products:

| SoldProducts |
| --- |
| ID |
| BatchSerialNumber |
| Quantity |

BatchSerialNumber in SoldProducts references the same column in StockedProducts.

My problem is when a Stocked batch runs out, I want to delete the record of it, while keeping all the records of its sale.

How would I manage that with a foreign key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My problem is when a Stocked batch runs out, I want to delete the record of it, while keeping all the records of its sale.
>
> How would I manage that with a foreign key?

The whole purpose of a foreign key is to maintain referential integrity of the children records to their parents. It is supposed to prevent someone from removing a parent that a child is a dependent on.

If you wanted to delete a parent and not the children in such a relationship, then either the business logic is flawed or there's a database design issue. It would be nonsensical, otherwise, to do so.

It appears your `StockedProduct` table has a `Quantity` column. So, it seems like it doesn't make sense to delete a row from it, rather it should stay at `Quantity 0` until it is restocked, or if it's never replenished, that's fine too. But the serialized product existed and the sale of it is dependent on that parent row.

Otherwise, if you truly wanted to delete from `StockedProducts` (which sounds like flawed business logic to me still), then you would need to redesign the database by removing the Foreign Key dependency from `SoldProducts`.

Comment: fair enough. thank you.

Comment: @AzzedineBk np, cheers!